# Is there any way to alter the response in an Angular 5 HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

For my application I have created the following `HttpInterceptor`. Is there a way to return an altered version of the response to the request subscribers from here?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // any way to alter response that gets sent to the request subscriber?
            }
        }, (error: any) => {    
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
                    console.log('The authentication session has expired or the user is not authorised. Redirecting to login page.');
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just like Marcel Lamothe pointed out in his answer, you can alter the response by cloning the event and changing the body property.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // change the response body here
                return event.clone({
                    body: 'myCustomResponse'
                });
            }

            return event;
        }).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
                    console.log('The authentication session has expired or the user is not authorised. Redirecting to login page.');
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what will happen to the subscriber observable which is waiting for the response?

Comment: @divine it will receive the altered response from the interceptor

Answer (score 5):

See the Immutability section of the Http guide:
https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability

> Interceptors exist to examine and mutate outgoing requests and incoming responses. However, it may be surprising to learn that the HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes are largely immutable.
>
> This is for a reason: because the app may retry requests, the interceptor chain may process an individual request multiple times. If requests were mutable, a retried request would be different than the original request. Immutability ensures the interceptors see the same request for each try.
>
> There is one case where type safety cannot protect you when writing interceptors—the request body. It is invalid to mutate a request body within an interceptor, but this is not checked by the type system.
>
> If you have a need to mutate the request body, you need to copy the request body, mutate the copy, and then use clone() to copy the request and set the new body.
>
> Since requests are immutable, they cannot be modified directly. To mutate them, use clone()