# Default Date to JSON conversion format in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-formly

Suppose a component (inside the angular app) having several reactive forms containing datepickers (I'm using `mat-datepicker` from angular material lib) and other inputs. After a user hit "Submit" button I send the value of forms to backed (with `HttpClient.post`). The problem is that datepicker fields are serialized as `"2020-11-18T22:00:00.000Z"` (obviously `Date.toJSON()` method is called) while backend expects other format.

Note that I'm using `formly` lib to build my forms, cause set of components on each form may vary. You might not be familiar with `formly` but anyway set of datepickers may vary as well, so I can't convert datepicker fields directly cause I don't know the exact list of date fields in a place where I send the value of forms.

Is there an elegant solution to my problem? Can't think up something better than monkey-patching `Date.prototype.toJSON()` or looping through objects sent on the server, check the type of fields and changing field if it's a `Date`? I can't find a way to set the format of value output by datepicker either in material or in formly.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215105/angular-httpclient-custom-json-parser-jsog

Comment: What you want is to customise how date are serialised, which is offered by `mat-datepicker` https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats

Comment: @maxime1992 please correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can see there's a way to customize parse and input formats, no way to explain `MatDatepicker` to put e.g. "YYYY-mm-DD" in form value

Comment: Did you think about creating a ControlValueAccessor implementation to wrap the datepicker component while changing the model in the  `writeValue` and before `onChange`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) would be an elegant solution. The idea is to create a date picker component that takes your date format as input and send back your format as output.

For that you just have to create a new component that I would call `MatDatepickerWrapperComponent` for this example. The template of this component would be nothing more than the material date picker :

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="modelChange($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

From the component side, you will have to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), and do the transformations you need :

```js
writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.model = transformDateFromMyFormatToIso(value);
}
```

```js
modelChange(value: string) {
    const transformedValue = transformIsoDateToMyFormat(value);
    this.onChange(transformedValue);
  }
```

You can now add the new component to a form the way you would have added the original one.

[Here is a running stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-65071518?file=src/app/mat-datepicker-wrapper/mat-datepicker-wrapper.component.ts)

Comment: Did this answer work in the context of a Formly datepicker field? The provided Stackblitz does not include Formly and I'm unable to duplicate the solution using Formly. [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-material-datepicker-p2ygu8?file=src/app/components/formly-datepicker-type/formly-datepicker-type.component.ts). On Simple example, DOB is using the Formly datepicker and Anniversary is using custom datepicker. Desired date output is "yyyy-M-d" after submitting.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck Yes it should work, here is documentation of how to add custom template to formly : https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use an HTTP interceptor. I think you might be able to use your interceptor to change all the dates in the body to something else.

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) is an example of how the interceptor works. In the example, a header is added. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149223/how-to-add-something-to-the-body-of-request-inside-an-angular-interceptor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400364/is-there-any-way-to-alter-the-response-in-an-angular-5-httpinterceptor/47412058) are an example of modifying the body.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I could solve this by overriding JSON date converter in the app component.:

```
overrideToJSONDate() {
    Date.prototype.toJSON = function () {
      return new Date(this).toLocaleString();
    }
  }
```

I call this function once in app component's constructor.
You can apply and logic inside the function but be sure, to return with current string.

Comment: And where do you think it's a best place to call this overrideToJSONDate() in angular app?

Comment: I called the function in the app.component's cunstructor once, and thats all. From there, all of your Date will be stringified by your funciton.